# Testing that there are no more non-space characters in the stream

Tags: c++, debugging, release, iostream, visual-studio-2010

Suppose I am writing an interpreter, and one of its commands has the form

```
define variable
```

where variable may only be a lowercase latin letter.

Here's what I am doing. After having determined that the command is a define command, I create a stream from the string, say `"define a"` (iss), then read the command name from it, assert that it's indeed "define".

```
std::istringstream iss(Command);
//read the word "define"
std::string cmdstr;
assert(iss >> cmdstr);
assert(cmdstr == DefineStr);
```

Then I read a character from the stream. The reading should succeed, so I check

```
if(!(iss >> var))
{
    errorMsg = "Invalid syntax of define command. Too few arguments\n";
    return false;
}
```

Then I must check that there are no more non-space characters in the stream, so I check

```
//the rest of the line must be empty;
if(iss >> var)
{
    errorMsg = "Invalid syntax of define command. Too many arguments\n";
    return false;
}
```

Is my strategy of testing that there are more characters in the stream ***wrong***? I know I could use regexes, spirit parsers and whatnot to solve this problem, but suppose I wish to stick to this approach. The problem is that in debug mode (MSVC10.0) the function works as expected when I input `define a` whereas in Release mode the function somehow gets into the `if(iss >> var)` and says `Invalid syntax of define command. Too many arguments`. I am stuck, I can't understand what's wrong.

The complete code of the function is as follows:

```
bool Interpreter::ExecuteDefineCommand(const std::string& Command, std::string& errorMsg)
{
    std::istringstream iss(Command);

    //read the word "define"
    std::string cmdstr;
    assert(iss >> cmdstr);
    assert(cmdstr == DefineStr);

    //read the variable name
    char var;
    if(!(iss >> var))
    {
        errorMsg = "Invalid syntax of define command. Too few arguments\n";
        return false;
    }
    if(!islower(var))
    {
        errorMsg = "You may define only lowercase variables\n";
        return false;
    }

    //the rest of the line must be empty;
    if(iss >> var)
    {
        errorMsg = "Invalid syntax of define command. Too many arguments\n";
        return false;
    }

    auto insertRes = variables.insert(std::make_pair(var, 0));

    if(!insertRes.second)
    {
        errorMsg = "The variable ";
        errorMsg += var;
        errorMsg += " has already been defined!\n";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
std::string cmdstr;
assert(iss >> cmdstr);
assert(cmdstr == DefineStr);
```

Because  operator >> is inside assert, it just doesn't get executed in Release mode! The correct approach would be

```
std::string cmdstr;
iss >> cmdstr;
assert(iss);
assert(cmdstr == DefineStr);
```